# C++ Pass bytes from char* to a BYTE*

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, char

I would like to know how to pass/COPY a sequence of bytes represented as a `char*` to a `BYTE*` in C++ in Windows.

Let's say I have this `char*` :

```
const char *ByteString = "\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B"
```

How would I COPY each byte from this char* to a `BYTE *Bytes` and vice-versa ?

EDIT: Thanks alot for everyone's help !

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the BYTE defined by the Windows API

Comment: Note that asking to convert from `const char *` to `Byte *` may give you different answers than converting to `const Byte *`.

Comment: @CataCata Just out of curiosity: Which API function are you calling?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am just using ReadProcessMemory and comparing bytes. Nothing fancy

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have an issue with the answer you provided... Let's say I have this char* ByteString = "\xA1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B". When checking to see if the copying was successful like so: std::cout << std::hex << (uintptr_t)(BytesPattern[i]) << std::dec << std::endl;   After reading the first /x00 the next bytes seem to be different from my char*

Comment: It is declared as in your basic_string example, so instead of Bytes, it's named BytesPattern. After copying the bytes from my char* to my BYTE* , I expect them to be the same, but here comes my problem when having \x00 in my char*. When printing my BYTE, I expect it to be : A1 00 00 ... 3B and so on, but what I get is A1 00 and random ones after the first 00 byte.

Comment: Ahh... if you copy literal strings, copying stops at the first `\0`. The basic_string is constructed that way. You need to add a length argument to the constructor if the string contains 0:s

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't get it, what does \0 have to do with copying the bytes? They are divided like so \x00

Comment: When the Bytes-string is constructed, the original string is supplied. Without a length argument it uses `strlen` to figure out the length of the string. That function stops at the first 0 it finds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried doing it this way in order to specify the length, but it still does the same thing. BYTE* Bytes = (BYTE* )calloc(BytesSize+ 1, sizeof(BYTE)); memmove(Bytes, BytesString, BytesSize); Where BytesSize is the number of bytes in my char*, not the string length.

Comment: @TedLyngmo nvm that was the issue.. I was using strcpy at some point and that was messing me up.. Thanks a lot for the help and patience

Comment: No problem! I added another example at the bottom of my answer that I think fit your needs better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `BYTE` is:

`typedef unsigned char       BYTE;`

which is not the same as a `const char`, so you'd need to convert it, but note that casting away `const` from something declared `const` to start with results in undefined behaviour and trying to actually change the data poses an even bigger risk.

`BYTE* Bytes = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(const_cast<char*>(ByteString));`

Edit: I just noticed that converting a `const char*` to a `BYTE*` was taken out of the question but I'll leave it here for now.

---

Copying the data (not as a zero terminated string) could be done like this:

```
const char ByteString[] = "\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B";
BYTE* Bytes = new BYTE[sizeof(ByteString)-1];
std::memcpy(Bytes, ByteString, sizeof(ByteString)-1);

// Use your Bytes

delete[] Bytes; // manual delete when you are done
```

---

Or better:

```
const char ByteString[] = "\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B";
std::basic_string<BYTE> Bytes( reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(ByteString), sizeof(ByteString)-1 );

// use Bytes
// Bytes.data()  returns a BYTE*
// Bytes.size()  returns the length.
```

---

But given the nature of what you are doing, you could probably skip these conversions and use an array of the correct type to start with:

```
BYTE Bytes[] = { 0xA1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xC8, 0x74, 0x1B };
```

or

```
std::basic_string<BYTE> Bytes({ 0xA1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xC8, 0x74, 0x1B });
```

These won't need any conversions when all you deal with is raw `BYTE` data. Here's an example using `ReadProcessMemory` and a `basic_string` for a buffer and pattern.

```
using BYTEstr = std::basic_string<BYTE>; // just for convenience

BYTEstr Buffer(1024, 0); // 1024 BYTES initialized with 0
BYTEstr Pattern({ 0xA1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xC8, 0x74, 0x1B });

ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, Buffer.data(), Buffer.size(), &lpNumberOfBytesRead);

BYTEstr::size_type pos = Buffer.find(Pattern);

if (pos == BYTEstr::npos) {
    std::cout << "Pattern not found\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Pattern found at position " << pos << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Technically, just const_casting something which is const * is UB, not changing the const value it points to. This is UB too, and any other proposed solution also is.

Comment: @N00byEdge can you back this up with some reference? Tbh I dont think so, because otherwise `const_cast` would be rather useless

Comment: Does casting it copy the bytes from my char * inside my BYTE * ? Since this is the final purpose. I may have formulated my question wrong.

Comment: Ah... no, the only thing copied is the pointer to the first character in the string.

Comment: No casting the pointer just makes it pretend it now points to `BYTE`s instead of `char`s. It does not create new ones.

Comment: @N00byEdge and how would one go about actually copying the bytes represented as a char* inside a BYTE* ?

Comment: Call me crazy, but if you could consider making a copy of the string, you could perfectly fine just copy it to a readwrite buffer.

Comment: I made a separate answer for the possibility of making a copy of all the characters to a readwrite buffer. @CataCata

Comment: @N00byEdge Great, I added making a `basic_string` version out of it to get some nifty string methods with it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Only problem with that is that it can't transfer the ownership to the called function in case it needs to. This would depend on the function in question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo when trying  to test if the copying was successful like so : std::cout << std::hex << (uintptr_t)(Bytes[0]) << std::dec << std::endl;   The bytes seem to not match my initial char*

Comment: @CataCata that's because of an error in your code (using `/` instead of ``\``)

Comment: @N00byEdge Sure, strings transfer ownership using move semantics which is a cleaner way to do it i.m.o.

Comment: @N00byEdge GOOD CATCH wholy I am as blind as a bat... Thanks alot everyone for the help! This solved my issue!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. But the API takes a `BYTE *`, possibly an owning one.

Comment: Then I'd propose to use my second solution and not the `basic_string` one.

Comment: Objects declared const need not actually exist in memory. So even reading from them through a non-const reference is undefined behavior.

Comment: No argument. It was a half pragmatic approach on my behalf since it's Windows and probably VS, it'll most likely work. Just noticed that N00byEdge said something simillar above too but I didn't notice. That's of course correct too.

Comment: @N00byEdge and Galik - updated my answer to mention the UB by just casting away the const.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why use new BYTE[sizeof(ByteString)-1]; ? Shouldn't I specify the number of bytes instead of the string length ? For example using this string "\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B" there are 4 bytes. Also, why the -1 ? Thanks again for your help !

Comment: The only reason is that when you use a string literal is that it automatically adds a `\0` at the end, making the data that you actually want to use one char extra.
If you use C strings (that are `\0` terminated) it'll be fine, but dealing with patterns where zeroes are big part of it - no. `sizeof`on a `char[]` willl give you the exact size - including the extra `\0`, that you do not need for pattern matching, hence the `-1` to remove it from the handling.

Answer (score 2):

To respect const, use

```
const BYTE *Bytes = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(ByteString);
```

and vice versa:

```
const char *ByteString = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(Bytes);
```

If you want to make copy of the buffer so that you can modify it, use

```
len = LenOfChrStr;
BYTE *Bytes = new BYTE[len];
memcpy(Bytes, ByteStr, len);
```

Comment: Ah, right: need to keep the const. I was just going by the question in the subject line. (char* -> BYTE*)

Comment: Will the length be equal to the number of bytes represented inside my char* or the char number?

Comment: Length is the number of bytes

Comment: Same with this method, when testing to see if the copying was successful, the bytes seem to not match my initial char* :  std::cout << std::hex << (uintptr_t)(Bytes[0]) << std::dec << std::endl; EDIT: I was using / instead of \ ..

Answer (score 1):

Given a `char const *` array of characters, we can make a new buffer with readwrite `BYTE`s for the API to possibly edit:

```
char const *ByteString = "\x3B\xC8\x74\x1B";
auto len = std::strlen(ByteString) + 1;
auto ptr = std::make_unique<BYTE[]>(len);
std::memcpy(ptr.get(), ByteString, len);
```

If you need to surrender the ownership of the memory to the function:

```
Func(ptr.release());
```

But if you want to keep the ownership yourself:

```
Func(ptr.get());
```

Comment: `len+1` I guess?

Comment: Good catch, darnit!

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC (I guess this is your compiler for WinAPI application) you can make the `char` type unsigned with `/J` option (more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned?view=vs-2017). If you do this, `BYTE` becomes the same as `char` and no conversion would be necessary.

Please note, this might have some other side effects in your application.

Comment: OP would still need a `const_cast`.